# Need help on finding similar keywords from the column which contain all the list of words in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a brand table with 2 columns, let's say for example,

```
------------------------------------------------
|Brand_id   |  Brand_name|
------------------------------------------------
| 54         | Samsung   |
------------------------------------------------
```

And another table containing search terms, for instance

```
query_id    query_text
12  Samsung_Refrigerator
13  LG_washing_machine
14  Sony_camera
15  Sony playstation
16  Why is the earth not flat
17  How to use BigQuery
```

Here, I want to pull all the search terms that include the brand name like '%Brand_name%' and here brand name can be any of the brands like Amazon, LG etc and Samsung is an example, here I have around 14000 brands  and I am working on big query.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression and `REGEXP_CONTAINS(value, regexp)`  function:

for example to get all brands that contains `sams` in their names:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
where REGEXP_CONTAINS(Brand_name, r'sams$');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, but here, I have around 14k brands where I have to pull all the terms which contain any of the brands in the term.
example: Samsung Refrigerator, Lg Washing Machine, Samsung TV as such

Comment: @kirantirupathi , well , I;m not following , you have a column called "brand_name" and if you want to pull them all , then select them all. but if you want to search inside that column, this answer your question.

Comment: I will be more precise, Let's say I have around 1 million search terms with the name "query" in the separate table- Table1 and now I wanted to pull only brand queries and example like "Samsung_Refrigerator", "LG_washing_machine" etc. But, the problem is, I have all this Brand names in the separate table, Table 2 with "Brand Code" as 1 column and "Brand Name" as another column, So, Now, I wanted to take all the Search terms which has Brand Name in them by mapping these 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a one off task and you don't need it in production, you can use your brands table to generate [parts of] the SQL statements, e.g.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(" OR Query like '%", Brand_name, "%' ") FROM Brands
```

Then output the result to a file and add the base SELECT to the top:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE 1=0 OR 
<Generated statements go here>
```

then you can execute the script and get the results

Answer (score 0):

Given your comments on @eshirvana answer, I re-created the two tables I think you have:

- a brand list table:

  WITH brands AS (
  SELECT 54 AS Brand_id, "Samsung" AS Brand_name
  UNION ALL SELECT 56, "LG"
  UNION ALL SELECT 59, "Sony")

[image]

- a search terms table:

  ```
    search_results AS (

    SELECT 12 AS query_id, "Samsung_Refrigerator" AS query_text
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 13, "LG_washing_machine"
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 14, "SONY_camera",
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 15, "Sony playstation",
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 16, "Why is the earth not flat"
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 17, "How to use BigQuery"

    )
  ```

[image]

From there you can extract the search terms containing one of your brand names through a JOIN:

```
SELECT
  s.query_id AS query_id,
  s.query_text AS query_text,
  b.Brand_name AS Brand_id
FROM
  search_results s
JOIN
  brands b
ON
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(UPPER(s.query_text),UPPER(b.Brand_name))
```

The result on the sample data:

[image]

Comment: Also watch out a join is an expensive operation, you should maybe try on a small representative sample of your data before running it on your whole table.

Comment: UPPER is for ignoring case (SONY and Sony are extracted)

Comment: Hi @Cylinby, here, there is no mapping between the 2 tables with any Id as such called, "query_id". I only have brand_id, brand_name in the brands table and in query table, I have search terms with other metrics

Comment: Then just leave the query_id out of the Select clause, it is not required.. the most important is the JOIN clause, which only requires the brand_name from your brand column, and the query_text column from the search terms